# What is AddOdata() alternative in Microsoft.AspNet.OData in .NET 6?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, odata, .net-6.0

As a novice, I am building .NET 6 Web API with Odata. Goal was to build project without use of Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData (I heard, that AspNetCore is better for MVC and Microsoft.AspNet.OData for Web API). However, this code `builder.Services.AddControllers().AddOData` is not working, because **"IMvcBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'AddOData' "**.

I tried calling AddOData with and without lambda function inside. Is there some alternative or workaround to this method in Microsoft.AspNet.OData?

Comment: [Microsoft.AspNet.OData](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.OData) is for the Web API 2 framework, on the old .NET Framework based ASP.NET platform. It's not for ASP.NET Core. The [Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData) package is for ASP.NET Core, where Web API is no longer a separate platform but instead a way of structuring your controllers. If you want to do OData in ASP.NET Core, that's what you should use, unless you want to rewrite the entire thing from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call `AddMvc()/AddControllers().AddOData()`, you'll have to install a package that provides that extension method, which is precisely what https://github.com/OData/AspNetCoreOData does.

It's not built into ASP.NET Core or anything.

See the example startup code in the OData repo: https://github.com/OData/AspNetCoreOData/blob/main/sample/ODataRoutingSample/Startup.cs

Comment: So it is not possible to use OData without that package?

Comment: It is, but then you'll have to implement all of it yourself.